# Rmarkdown knit suddenly failing

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, chocolatey

Knitting Rmd files was working when I last tried 2 days ago. Without knowingly changing anything in the meantime, knitting now fails, with 1000s of

[image: Chocolatey Shim]

processes generated before falling over. Even on a fresh default .Rmd file. The computer has been re-booted. Anyone have a clue what might have caused this and how to fix it?

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          2.2
year           2022
month          10
day            31
svn rev        83211
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this.

There were several versions of pandoc installed, perhaps controlled centrally.

The version here C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\pandoc.exe
would generate some sort of recursive call. It was possible to reproduce this
recursion with a simple -v flag

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\pandoc.exe -v.

This was pandoc v 3.0.

When I choco uninstalled this, RStudio then found the version of pandoc bundled with RStudio, and the documents would knit fine again.